# ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] windows server 2008 r2

Tags: oracle, odbc, windows-server-2008-r2

I am using Microsoft Odbc driver for Oracle in windows server 2008 r2 using C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe but getting following error.

ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

There is No ODBC 64 bit driver in windows server 2008 r2

Guide me What I do?

Comment: Are you trying to connect using a program you've written, or are you using an application to connect to your database?

Comment: Does the DSN being specified in your application match the DSN created in the ODBC Administrator?